# EF Core 3 evaluate navigation property null on server

Tags: ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

I have a request

```
DbContext.Invoices
.Where(x => x.Status != InvoiceStatus.Draft && x.PaymentMethod == PaymentMethod.DirectDebit)
.Where(x => x.DirectDebitFile == null).ToList();
```

**DirectDebitFile** is a reverse navigation property.

Which was working fine in EF Core 2, not sure about how it was evaluated in the final request.
After upgrade to EF Core 3, this request doesn't work anymore and says

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Invoice>
    .Where(i => !(i.IsDeleted))
    .Where(i => i.ClubId == __CurrentUser_ClubId_0)
    .Cast()
    .Where(e => e.FederationId == __CurrentUser_FederationId_1)
    .Cast()
    .Where(e0 => !(e0.Hidden))
    .Cast()
    .Where(e1 => (int)e1.Status != 0 && (Nullable<int>)e1.PaymentMethod == (Nullable<int>)DirectDebit)
    .LeftJoin(
        outer: DbSet<DirectDebitFile>
            .Where(d => !(d.IsDeleted)), 
        inner: e1 => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(e1, "Id"), 
        outerKeySelector: d => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(d, "InvoiceId"), 
        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Invoice, DirectDebitFile>(
            Outer = o, 
            Inner = i
        ))
    .Where(e1 => e1.Inner == null)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

I can rewrite this query and make it work by moving evaluation to the client-side

```
DbContext.Invoices
.Include(x=>x.DirectDebitFile)
.Where(x => x.Status != InvoiceStatus.Draft && x.PaymentMethod == PaymentMethod.DirectDebit)
.AsEnumerable()
.Where(x => x.DirectDebitFile == null).ToList();
```

But in this case, of course, the query will pull up all the rows and filtering x.DirectDebitFile == null will be on the client-side. I want this query to be evaluated on the server, please help to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I changed the request as the way as normal SQL check it, by checking one of the joined table field

```
AppDbContext.Invoices.Include(x => x.DirectDebitFile)
                .Where(x => x.Status != InvoiceStatus.Draft)
                .Where(x => x.DirectDebitFile.FileName == null);
```